# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog goes out of screen when the message is large

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, 
                              message,
                              "title",
                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

The message can be 10 lines and message can be 500 lines. It changes dynamically. I want to implement a scroll bar if the message exceeds the screen height.

So I tried:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea (message);
JscrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                              scrollPane,
                              "title",
                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

This will open a dialog and a scroll bar in windows and it works fine, but in mac os the dialog goes out of screen.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the preferred size for your `scrollPane` before showing the dialog to limit its size:

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
```

The dimension to use can be based on the screen size that you can retrieve like this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```

Note that I have not tested this on other platforms than Mac OS X.